# Incorrect marker sizes with Seaborn relplot and scatterplot relative to legend

Tags: pandas, seaborn

I'm trying to understand how to get the legend examples to align with the dots plotted using Seaborn's `relplot` in a Jupyter notebook. I have a `size` (`float64`) column in my pandas `DataFrame` `df`:

```
sns.relplot(x="A", y="B", size="size", data=df)
```

The values in the `size` column are `[0.0, -7.0, -14.0, -7.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 8.0, 2.0, 0.0, -4.0, 7.0, -4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 1.0, 7.0]` and as you can see, the minimum value is `-14` and the maximum value is `8`. It looks like the legend is aligned well with that. However, look at the actual dots plotted, there's a dot considerably smaller than the one corresponding to `-16` in the legend. There's also no dot plotted as large as the `8` in the legend.

What am I doing wrong -- or is this a bug?

[image: Example of sizes not occurring in the dataset]

I'm using pandas 0.24.2 and seaborn 0.9.0.

---

**Edit**:
Looking closer at the [Seaborn relplot example](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/scatter_bubbles.html):

[image: relplot example]

the smallest weight is 1613 but there's an orange dot to the far left in the plot that's smaller than the dot for 1500 in the legend. [I think this points to this being a bug](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/1763).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what seaborn does here, but if you're willing to use matplotlib alone, it could look like

```
import numpy as np; np.random.rand
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

s = [0.0, -7.0, -14.0, -7.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 8.0, 2.0, 
     0.0, -4.0, 7.0, -4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 1.0, 7.0]
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, len(s))
y = np.sin(x)
df = pd.DataFrame({"A" : x, "B" : y, "size" : s})

# calculate some sizes in points^2 from the initial values
smin = df["size"].min()
df["scatter_sizes"] = 0.25 * (df["size"] - smin + 3)**2
# state the inverse of the above transformation
finv = lambda y: 2*np.sqrt(y)+smin-3

sc = plt.scatter(x="A", y="B", s="scatter_sizes", data=df)
plt.legend(*sc.legend_elements("sizes", func=finv), title="Size")

plt.show()
```

[image]

More details are in the [Scatter plots with a legend example](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_with_legend.html#automated-legend-creation).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the example code, I will likely use that instead and try to style the output similar to Seaborn's. Unless someone comes up with a workaround for Seaborn, I will accept this as the answer.

Comment: It seems like this is actually a bug, see edit/bug report in the question.