# How to manually scale a continuous legend in a seaborn scatterplot?

Tags: data-visualization, seaborn, legend, scatter-plot

I'm creating a scatterplot with seaborn like this:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20,5))
ax = sns.scatterplot(x=x,
        y=y,
        hue=errors,
        s=errors*20,
        alpha=0.8,
        edgecolors='w')
ax.set(xlabel='X', ylabel='Y')
ax.legend(title="Error (m)", loc='upper right')
```

My errors contain values between approximately 0.1 and 12.5. However, for my legend seaborn automatically generates labels 0, 5, 10, 15. This makes my algorithm look worse than it is. I would like to change the step size in the legend while maintaining a correct mapping between colors and error magnitudes. For example 0, 4, 8, 12.5. Is this possible?

Comment: You could use the approach of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56609180/incorrect-marker-sizes-with-seaborn-relplot-and-scatterplot-relative-to-legend) and add color as an extra parameter. Note how in that post the size parameter of seaborn's scatter is interpreted quite different than in matplotlib's scatter.